# Python Regex Match Line If Ends With?

Tags: python, regex

This is what im trying to scrape:

```
        <p>Some.Title.html<br />
<a href="https://www.somelink.com/yep.html" rel="nofollow">https://www.somelink.com/yep.html</a><br />
Some.Title.txt<br />
<a href="https://www.somelink.com/yeppers.txt" rel="nofollow">https://www.somelink.com/yeppers.txt</a><br />
```

I have tried several variations of the following:

```
match = re.compile('^(.+?)<br \/><a href="https://www.somelink.com(.+?)">',re.DOTALL).findall(html)
```

I am looking to match lines with the "p" tag and without.  "p" tag only occurs on the first instance.  Terrible at python so I am pretty rusty, have searched through here and google and nothing seemed to be quite the same.  Thanks for any help.  Really do appreciate the help I get here when I am stuck.

Desired output is an index:

```
<a href="Some.Title.html">http://www.SomeLink.com/yep.html</a>
<a href="Some.Title.txt">http://www.SomeLink.com/yeppers.txt</a>
```

Comment: A tip: Don't use `regex` to parse html, use something built for that, like BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I have no clue how to use beautiful soup.  It is so rare I get into anything like this.  Appreciate your advise, I really should learn for these silly moments however.

Comment: It's just that if you really need to dig into html parsing, it's really recommended to use something written for that, because `regex` can't handle nested patterns. What would be the desired output?

Comment: Desired output is and index:

Wont come up right here ill put it in description

Comment: *It is so rare I get into anything like this* => Rare opportunity to learn ! Beautiful Soup is a better solution suited for this usecase as @ViníciusAguiar mentions

Comment: I appreciate the advise I will put some time into BeautifulSoup.  Thanks folks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 

This might be helpful :) As the other comments above have mentioned, do try out BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Beautiful soup and requests module would be perfect for something like this instead of regex as the commenters noted above.

```
import requests
import bs4

html_site = 'www.google.com' #or whatever site you need scraped
site_data = requests.get(html_site) # downloads site into a requests object
site_parsed = bs4.BeautifulSoup(site_data.text) #converts site text into bs4 object
a_tags = site_parsed.select('a') #this will select all 'a' tags and return list of them
```

This just a simple code that will select all the  tags from the html site and store them in a list with the format that you illustrated up above.  I'd advise checking [here](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/) for a nice tutorial on bs4 and [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) for the actual docs.